# Hibernate: Using entity with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table with composite primary key:

Taking example from tables from other question in SO

the composite primary key class:

```
@Embeddable 
public class TimePK implements Serializable {     
protected Integer levelStation;     
protected Integer confPathID;  
protected Integer col1;
protected Integer col2;    

public TimePK() {}      

public TimePK(Integer levelStation, Integer confPathID, Integer col1, Integer col2) {         
this.levelStation = levelStation;         
this.confPathID = confPathID; 
this.col1 = col1;
this.col2 = col2; 

}     

// equals, hashCode 
}
```

and the entity:

```
@Entity 
class Time implements Serializable {     

@EmbeddedId     
private TimePK timePK;      

private String src;     
private String dst;     
private Integer distance;     
private Integer price;      
//... 
}
```

There will be two entries in persistent.xml as:

com.somepackage.Time
com.somepackage.TimePK

Question:

How to use above classes in a query??
e.g. Find confPathId, col2 where levelstation is 10 and col1 is 20  -- what will be hibernate query for this requirement ?

Using "from TimePK T" in the query is giving "TimePK is not mapped" error!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf).

Section `2.4.1.3 Examples of Derived Identities` defines **a lot** of examples.

Comment: "from Time T where T.timePK.levelStation = 10 and T.timePK.col1 = 20"   correct ??

Answer (score 0):

Your TimePK is not a real entity (mapped to a table in db), it's a virtual object to contain PK of your Time object.
You should find Time object, not TimePK.